# преобразовать -3 из строки в список python

Tags: python

На вход подается строка '0 -3 1'.
Когда я пытаюсь привести ее к списку получается это `a = ['0','-', '3','1']`.
Мне нужно чтобы это имело вид `a = [0,-3,1]`.
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Мой код:

```
a = list(input()) 
a.remove(' ') 
a.remove(' ') 
print(a)
```

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста ваш код.

Comment: a = list(input())
a.remove(' ')
a.remove(' ')
print(a)

Comment: Вставьте код в вопрос нажав кнопку "править"

Comment: Вот как вариант - `a = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

input() возвращает строку, а простой кастинг строки в список (list()) разбивает строку побуквенно (то же самое происходит если обращаться со строкой как со списком: слайсить str[5:8], обходить for c in str, итд).

как правильно подсказали в комментариях, вам нужно разделить строку по пробелам:

```
input().split()
```

но там в конце строки может быть перевод строки или пробел, поэтому сначала их удалим:

```
input().strip().split()
```

теперь получился список строк, вроде `['0','-3','1']`,
сделаем из них числа: нужно применить int() к каждому элементу массива, это и делает map:

```
map(int, input().strip().split()))
```

ну и поскольку map() возвращает итератор, сделаем из него список

```
list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
```